# Cómo hacer que Excel no me cambie de formato la fecha cuando uso concatenar?

Tags: excel

Tengo una tabla de datos que va más o menos así

```
    A   |  B |    C   |   D    |    E
Cliente | id | gastos | moneda | fecha
Cliente1| 01 | 5000   | CAD    | 1/29/2019 0:00
Cliente2| 02 | 10000  | ARS    | 02/01/2019  00:00:00
Cliente3| 03 | 100000 | COP    | 2/27/2019 0:00
```

Cuando utilizo la función concatenar para crear un script de SQL me genera algo así

```
Cliente | id | gastos | moneda | fecha                | Script
Cliente1| 01 | 5000   | CAD    | 1/29/2019 0:00       | ('Cliente1','01',5000,'CAD','1/29/2019 0:00'),
Cliente2| 02 | 10000  | ARS    | 02/01/2019  00:00:00 | ('Cliente2','02',10000,'ARS','43467'),
Cliente3| 03 | 100000 | COP    | 2/27/2019 0:00       | ('Cliente3','03',100000,'COP','2/27/2019 0:00'),
```

Mi pregunta es con el cliente 2 en el que la notación de la fecha cambia, cómo puedo hacer para que al usar la función concatenar me dé la fecha tal cual es, no de esa manera?

=CONCATENATE("('";A2;"','";B2;"',";C2;",'";D2;"','";E2;"'),")

Agradezco mucho la ayuda!

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer algunas celdas de `fecha` han sido convertidas de texto normal a fecha (puede ocurrir cuando editas la celda y tiene un formato de fecha valido), por lo que la formula te esta entregando el valor numerico de la fecha (43467). Para evitar esto, usa la funcion TEXT() y un formato de fecha adecuado (mm/dd/yyyy por ejemplo)

```
=CONCATENATE("('";A2;"','";B2;"',";C2;",'";D2;"','";TEXT(E2;"mm-dd-yyyy");"'),")
```